# How to remove the rowdata when response is false which is added on true as response in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

Hai i have set of data which is pushed on response as true, now before submit button, i am changing the option so that i get response as false, so in this i need to remove that particular item which is pushed into the array.

TS:

```
onChangeMedication(value, rowData) {
    let exe = this.exeTypeNumber(value);
    this.medicationTableValue.map(details => {
      let medicationObj = { ...medicationFields };
      if (details.code === rowData.code) {
        if (value != '17587') {
          let params = { PatientId: this.userId, ExeType: exe, TableId: 'medication', Param1: rowData.name, Param2: rowData.date ? new DatePipe('en').transform(rowData.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') : null, Param3: null }
          this.emrservice.ccdRecord(params)
            .subscribe((res) => {
              this.validStatus(res.Body.Data, rowData);
              if (res.Body.Data) {
                this.exportCCDSuperObj.medication.push(medicationObj);
              } 
            });
        }
      };
    });
  }
```

This gives the api response as true or false

```
validStatus(data, rowData) {
    this.isValidItems = data
    if (!this.isValidItems) {
      rowData.showNoStatus = true;
      rowData.showYesStatus = false;
      this.isDisabled = false;
    } if (this.isValidItems) {
      rowData.showYesStatus = true;
      rowData.showNoStatus = false;
      this.isDisabled = true;
    }

  }
```

HTML:

```
<td>
              <select (change)="onChangeMedication($event.target.value,rowData)" [value]="defaultValue">
                <option value=''>Select Record</option>
                <option *ngFor="let sType of validType" [value]='sType.Id'>{{sType.Description}}</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" *ngIf="rowData.showNoStatus"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-check" *ngIf="rowData.showYesStatus"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the item from your array with generating a new array not including your specific item like

```
this.yourArray = this.yourArray.filter(element => element.property == “Somthing”);
```

This will generate a new array and pits its value in your new array with out any element matches your equation.

Comment: Thanks for response, i need to remove that particular rowData which is pushed into that array.

Comment: `this.exportCCDSuperObj.medication.filter(m => m.name == “name”)`

Comment: i had pushed an item into array when response is true in dropdown selection, now i changed the value of dropdown so i got response as false, so i must remove that particular rowdata from the array to which i have pushed

Comment: So you want to remove this item in validStatus after giving false on your sent data ?

Comment: ya i want to remove that particular object pushed into this  this.exportCCDSuperObj.medication, incase i get false as response

Comment: But why you are pushing this to your object and you checking the validStatus before ??

Comment: this valid status is just for the purpose of checking whether data is present in db r not, so if user selects one option and incasehe changes the option then the data pushed should be removed, incase if its added

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way and i was able to get as per my requirement.
So now i am able to delete the item which is added to the array on click of response change

TS:

```
onChangeMedication(value, rowData) {
    let exe = this.exeTypeNumber(value);
    this.medicationTableValue.map(details => {
      let medicationObj = { ...medicationFields };
      if (details.code === rowData.code) {
        if (value != '17587') {
          let params = { PatientId: this.userId, ExeType: exe, TableId: 'medication', Param1: rowData.name, Param2: rowData.date ? new DatePipe('en').transform(rowData.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') : null, Param3: null }
          this.emrservice.ccdRecord(params)
            .subscribe((res) => {
              this.validStatus(res.Body.Data, rowData);
              if (res.Body.Data) {
                this.exportCCDSuperObj.medication.push(medicationObj);
              } else {
                var index = this.exportCCDSuperObj.medication.indexOf(rowData);
                this.exportCCDSuperObj.medication.splice(index, 1);
              }
            });
        }
      };
    });
  }
```